# how to add xml mahout classifier jar into hadoop cluster, as i dont want to add that library into hadoop classpath

Tags: hadoop, xml-parsing, mapreduce

I am parsing xml file using XMLInputFormat.class which is present in mahout-exmaples jar. but while running the jar file of map reduce i am getting below error

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.XmlInputFormat not found

Please let me know how can i make these jars available while running on multinode hadoop cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Include the all mahout-examples JARs in the “-libjars” command line option of the hadoop jar ... command. The jar will be placed in distributed cache and will be made available to all of the job’s task attempts. More specifically, you will find the JAR in one of the `${mapred.local.dir}/taskTracker/archive/${user.name}/distcache/… subdirectories` on local nodes.

Please refer this [link](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/) for more details.

Comment: tried adding jars using 
hadoop jar /path/of/jar
then gave below command
hadoop jar /path of mapreduce jar/ mainClass input output

still got same error

Comment: If the above option is not working try this - Include the referenced JAR (all mahout jars)in the lib subdirectory of the submittable JAR(mapreduce jar): A MapReduce job will unpack the JAR from this subdirectory on the TaskTracker nodes and point your tasks to this directory to make the JAR available to your code.